# Phoenix Framework and AngularJS templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, phoenix-framework

How can I load AngularJS templates from a Phoenix framework application? I am using the ui-router to load a template using templateUrl. This is with angular 1.5.

```
myAppModule.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

 $stateProvider
    .state('event', {
        url: '/event',
        templateUrl: '/templates/event/event.html'
        // template: '<h1>Stuff</h1>'
    })


 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/event');
}]);
```

Loading an inline template works, so it is clearly the mechanism for loading templates which I am struggling with. 
Are there any settings in the brunch config I need to change?

Thank you

Eamon

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not too simple. I fall into the same problem, so here is my solution. Phoenix Framework has a directory where you can put your HTML files, the name of the directory is `web/static/assets`, you can set your files there, but if you need to create a directory like `web/static/assets/templates` you need to add exception in the `endpoint.ex`, like:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images templates js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

Now you can recompile and run your Elixir code and load your file like:

```
myAppModule.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

 $stateProvider
    .state('event', {
        url: '/event',
        templateUrl: 'templates/event/event.html'
    })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/event');
}]);
```

I hope that works for you too.